# DBeaver/Oracle wrong datetime pattern includes .0 at end

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

Using DBeaver and Oracle, select querys shows date in a wrong format, which always includes .0 at the end, like 2019-05-17 16:10:47.0.

To update/insert any date column in a table, on DBeaver editor, doesn't matter the date pattern I try, throws:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual
-- returns date with .0: 2019-05-17 17:21:11.0

SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
-- returns ok: 2019-05-17 17:21:11
```

It's ok on Oracle SQL Developer.

I also tried removing SSXFF from NLS_PARAMETERS, but doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters

--NLS_DATE_FORMAT   DD/MM/RR
--NLS_TIME_FORMAT   HH24:MI:SSXFF
--NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT  DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
--NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT    HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
--NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT   DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR

alter session set NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS'
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS'
alter session set NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS TZR'
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS TZR'
```

Environment: 
Windows 10
Oracle Database 12c 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit 
DBeaver 6.0.3
Driver OJDBC7

Comment: Java tag has been removed.

Comment: Use `Alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` in order to set "default" format of date in TO_CHAR function. Seems DBeaver set's this parameter incorectly .

Comment: `Alter session set nls_date_format = '...'` doesn't change it.

Comment: Any news on this topic? It's quite bothering...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on DBeaver Preferences > Data Formats > "Disable date / time formatting" option is unchecked.

Thats allows to use client-side formats on insert/update actions.

Answer (score 0):

In *Connection settings* > *Driver properties* change `oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp` to `FALSE`.

[image: Connection settings]